# Summing the value of the aggregate function Last()

Tags: sum, aggregate, ssrs-2012

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOfGb.png)I am trying to design a report in ssrs that returns the last opening stock for each product in the dataset. To achieve this I used

```
=Last(Fields!CustProdAdj_new_openingstockValue.Value).
```

This works fine. But where I encountered a problem is in getting the sum of all the opening stock for each product. I tried using

```
=sum(Last(Fields!CustProdAdj_new_openingstockValue.Value))
```

but I got the error message
[Error on Preview]

[image]

Please is there another way to go about this

I have tried using aggregate(), runningValue(), to no avail

This is the dataset

[image]

This is the report layout

[image]

[On previewing having used max()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMi11.png)

Comment: As the error says, you cannot use Last within an aggregate. There may be some different options you can try but it would be helpful if you can share some sample data and your current report design, then I might be able to offer an answer.

Comment: @AlanSchofield thanks for the response. Basically what I trying to achieve is to get the last created custprodadj record in a list of custprodadj records. Each time the customer product table is created, a replicate of the customer product is created in the custprodadj table which consists of three main fields, the product name, the opening stock, closing stock and the product brand

Comment: Using the last record, I can be able to get the latest opening and closing stock for each product but I also want to be able to see the total sum of all the opening and closing stock

Comment: I have added a snapshot of the dataset and report layout in the question body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably easier to do directly in the dataset query but assuming you cannot change that, then this should work...

This assumes your data is ordered by the `CustProdAdj_createdon` column and that this is a date, datetime or some other ordered value, change this bit if required.

```
=SUM(
     IIF(Fields!CustProdAdj_createdon.Value = Max(Fields!CustProdAdj_createdon.Value, "MyRowGroupNameHere"),
         CustProdAdj_new_openingstockValue,
         0)
    )
```

Change the MyRowGroupNameHere to be the name of the rowgroup spelled exactly as it is in the rowgroup panel below the main design panel. Case sensitive and include quotes.

What this does is, for each row within the rowgroup "MyRowGroupNameHere", compare the `CustProdAdj_createdon` date to the max `CustProdAdj_createdon` across the rowgroup. . If it is the same then return the `CustProdAdj_new_openingstockValue` else return 0.

This will return the value required on only 1 record within the group.

For example, if you had 1 row per day then only on the last day of the month would a value be returned other than 0 because only the date of the last record would match the maximum date within the group.

Then it simply sums the results of this up.

Comment: Thanks alot, I would definitely try this out and provide feedback

Comment: I tried it out with the max() but what I observed is instead of summing the values in the rows, it only returning the earliest created value in the rows. I have attached the report preview in the question body

Comment: You mentioned I could apply my filter in the dataset query. Is there a way I can do this instead if using the Last() function

Comment: It should work (I have tested it on some sample data). If this does answer the original question then mark it as accepted and then create a new question if you need to. Anyway, all I meant was you could get the answers via SQL rather than trying to do this in SSRS expressions, but try this first, I'm sure it will work.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you could supply some sample data (as text not an image) as it is returned from your dataset query, it will make it much easier to replicate your issue.

Comment: I would try it in SQL as suggested